# Multiple constructor and implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I have some scala code

```
class A (a: Int, b:Int) (implicit typeinfo: TypeInformation[T]) {
  ...
}
```

but if i define a new constructor

```
class A (a: Int, b:Int) (implicit typeinfo: TypeInformation[T]) {
  def this(a: Int]) {
      this(a, 0)   
  }
  ...
}
```

the compiler throws "could not find implicit value for parameter" error. I tried `this(a,0)(typeinfo)` but got the same error

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main constructor is the one when you defined at the class declaration

`this` is a secondary constructor and it's still a function, you need to define the implicit in the declaration.

if you do this:

```
class A (a: Int, b:Int) (implicit typeinfo: TypeInformation[T]) {
  def this(a: Int])(implicit typeinfo: TypeInformation[T]) {
      this(a, 0)   
  }
  ...
}
```

It will work.